# Is there any actual way to pull in a featured image from a blog post into a div on another page template as a background image

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a grid of blog posts to my homepage template. I have pulled in the content from 4 blog posts, now I just need to pull in the featured image as a background for each div.

Here is my current, half finished code, the background inline style isnt actually working right now, and I can't figure out why.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Home Content Template*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>



<div class="row show-grid lrds-hm-grd-wrppr">
  <div class="span2 lrds-hm-grd-bx lrds-hm-grd-bx-2" data-original-title="" title="" style="background url (<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id1, 'full'); ?>) center center;  background-size: cover;  background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <?php
    $post_id1 = 172;
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id1);
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="span2 lrds-hm-grd-bx lrds-hm-grd-bx-2" data-original-title="" title="" style="background url (<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id2, 'full'); ?>) center center;   background-size: cover;   background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <?php
    $post_id2 = 174;
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id2);
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="span3 lrds-hm-grd-bx lrds-hm-grd-bx-3" data-original-title="" title="" style="background url (<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id3, 'full'); ?>) center center;   background-size: cover;   background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <?php
    $post_id3 = 176;
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id3);
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="span4 lrds-hm-grd-bx lrds-hm-grd-bx-4" data-original-title="" title="" style="background url (<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id4, 'full'); ?>) center center;   background-size: cover;   background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <?php
    $post_id4 = 210;
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id4);
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">

      <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
         <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
          <?php the_title('<h2>','</h2>'); ?>
          <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

      <?php
          // tags anyone?
          the_tags();

        ?>
         <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php if (!is_singular()) : ?>
        <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php else : ?>

      <div class="alert alert-info">
        <strong>No content in this loop</strong>
      </div>

      <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">

      <?php
       if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar')) : //  Sidebar name
      ?>
      <?php
           endif;
      ?>
    </div>

  </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You need to pass te post id to thumbnail url that you need. After full give. ,  $post_id

Comment: So, do you mean just add it here and it should show up? Or is there something else I am missing...?


  <div class="span2 lrds-hm-grd-bx lrds-hm-grd-bx-2" data-original-title="" title="" style="background:URL(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full', $post_id ); ?>) center center;   background-size: cover;   background-repeat: no-repeat;">

Comment: have put an answer, just try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes just pass it like this in all your

```
background url (<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url (get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id($post_id)); ?>)
```

Comment: I thought that is what you meant. Unfortunately, I tried that early on, and it doesn't work at all. I was wondering if maybe there is something else I am supposed to do, like in functions.php or something?

Comment: and do change the variable names lik post_id1 , post_id2. dont keep them same

Comment: Ug, I still can't get it to work. This is a doozy. Maybe I applied you answer wrong? Doesn't seem like it though.

Comment: <div class="row show-grid lrds-hm-grd-wrppr"> <div class="span2 lrds-hm-grd-bx lrds-hm-grd-bx-2" data-original-title="" title="" style="background url (<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id1, 'full'); ?>) center center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;"> 

<?php 
$post_id1 = 172; $queried_post = get_post($post_id1); ?> <h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?>

</h2> <?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?> </div>

Comment: So what happened?

Comment: Nothing happened, it's still not pulling in the featured image for the background. I have no idea why, this all looks right to me. So I'm just totally confused why.

Comment: As you can see, I am having no problem pulling the post content. But the featured images aren't pulling in to the background of each div.

http://imgur.com/a/x6Pjv

Comment: Can you see the source and tell me what is getting printed out in the url portion

Comment: <div class="span2 lrds-hm-grd-bx lrds-hm-grd-bx-2" data-original-title="" title="" style="background url (<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: post_id1 in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lourdes-cardio/wp-content/themes/LourdesBS/page-templates/home-content.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
) center center;  background-size: cover;  background-repeat: no-repeat;">

Comment: It's odd, because I definitely have the variable defined.

Comment: have edited my ans and declare that post id before the div starting

Comment: it will work now as it was not getting the post id. for every image declare the post id before the divs

Comment: So now I just get a syntax error and my page breaks. It doesn't look like its missing anything though.

Comment: <?php
    $post_id1 = 172;
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id1);
    ?>

<div class="row show-grid lrds-hm-grd-wrppr">
  <div class="span2 lrds-hm-grd-bx lrds-hm-grd-bx-2" data-original-title="" title="" style="background url (<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url (get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id($post_id)); ?>)
 center center;   background-size: cover;   background-repeat: no-repeat;">

Comment: Exprator, Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Dont forget to thumbs up the answer and vote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a working file with the background image being pulled in from the featured image of the same page, not a separate blog post (which is what I am currently trying to do on a different template)

'code'

```
<?php $title = trim(get_field("custom_headline"));
    // check for custom title different from page name
    if ($title == "") {
        $title = Trim(get_the_title()); 
    }        
 ?>
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
<?php
    global $related_du;
    $rel = $related_du->show( get_the_ID(), true );
    $boxTitle = array();
    $boxContent = array();
    $i = 0;

    // Display the title of each related post
    if( is_array( $rel ) && count( $rel ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $rel as $r ) {
            if ( is_object( $r ) ) {
                if ($r->post_status != 'trash') {
                    //echo get_the_title( $r->ID ) . '<br />';
                    //echo get_post($post = $r->ID ) . '<br />';

                    $displayString = "";
                    $content_post = get_post($r->ID);
                    $boxTitle[$i] = $content_post->post_title;
                    $content = $content_post->post_content;
                    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

                    $boxContent[$i] =  $content;
                    $i++;


                }
            }
        }
    }
?>



<div class="hero2box" style="background:URL(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>) center center;  background-size: cover;     background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 tanLeft">
        <h4><?php echo $boxTitle[0] ; ?></h4>
        <hr class="red">
        <?php echo $boxContent[0] ; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 tanRight">
        <h4><?php echo $boxTitle[1] ; ?></h4>
        <hr class="red">
        <?php echo $boxContent[1] ; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">





       <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <?php the_content(); ?>


            <?php //echo get_post_type(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php
            // tags anyone?
            the_tags();

        ?>
       <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if (!is_singular()) : ?>
        <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <strong>No content in this loop</strong>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>




</div>

<div class="col-md-2">

    <?php
     if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar')) : //  Sidebar name
    ?>
    <?php
         endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

```
<?php
    global $related;
    $rel = $related->show( get_the_ID(), true );

    // Display the title of each related post
    if( is_array( $rel ) && count( $rel ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $rel as $r ) {
            if ( is_object( $r ) ) {
                if ($r->post_status != 'trash') {
                    //echo get_the_title( $r->ID ) . '<br />';
                    //echo get_post($post = $r->ID ) . '<br />';

                    $displayString = "";
                    $content_post = get_post($r->ID);
                    $content = $content_post->post_content;
                    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

                    $displayString = $displayString  . $content .  "";
                    echo $displayString;


                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

'code'

Answer (score 0):

Ok Solved! I had to be more simple, cuz I'm dumb sometimes. :P

```
<?php
    $post_id1 = 172;
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id1);
?>
<div class="row show-grid lrds-hm-grd-wrppr">
  <div class="span2 lrds-hm-grd-bx lrds-hm-grd-bx-2"   style="background:url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id1)); ?>)    ">

    <h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?>
  </div>
```